# TypeScript GET Request max body size (Chrome, Edge - axios, node-fetch fetch)

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, axios, node-fetch

I am requesting large JSON payload with GET request that is gzip compressed.
69MB compressed 531MB uncompressed works fine
69MB compressed 537MB uncompressed gives empty string as body

- I can see Chrome is able to get data and uncompress it

I've tried 2 different applications on my side, older one with typescript from 4 years ago and the most recent one and getting the same results.
Tried to use axios node-fetch fetch libraries, but getting the same results.

I cant find any documentation about limits from Chrome/Request, although I am getting the same issue with Edge browser.

Any suggestions?